# QQ-Plot interpretation

Tags: r, regression, qq-plot

I am working with a dataset (900 observations) and have the following normal QQ plot in R:

[image]

Seeing that the QQ-plot little bit strange, what could I infer about the underlying distribution? It seems to me that a distribution has too many pikes at 2, is that right? Also, what other conclusions can we draw from the data?

Comment: Your distribution is approximately symmetric but has much higher kurtosis than the normal. That's not "a little bit strange", but a common phenomenon. I don't see a spike at 2 but rather a peak density of nearly 2.